# Two 2nd order homogeneous ODEs with the same solution space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have two 2nd order ODEs:
$$a_2(x)y''(x)+a_1(x)y'(x)+a_0(x)y(x)=0$$
$$b_2(x)y''(x)+b_1(x)y'(x)+b_0(x)y(x)=0$$
such that they both have exactly the same solutions (the two $2$d solution spaces identify).
Can we deduce that there exists $c(x)$ such that $a_i(x)=c(x)b_i(x)$ for all $i=0,1,2$?

It seems right to me but I can't really show that it's true. Help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $a_2$ and $b_2$ are never zero.   Then we can divide by them to reduce to the case $a_2 = b_2 = 1$, where we want to show $a_1 = b_1$ and $a_0 = b_0$.  If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent solutions of $y'' + a_1(x) y' + a_0(x) y = 0$, their Wronskian 
$W = y_1 y_2' - y_1' y_2$ is nonzero and satisfies Abel's equation $W' + a_1 W = 0$.  Thus $a_1(x) = -W'(x)/W(x)$ is determined by the solutions, and so is
$a_0(x) = (-y_1''(x) - a_1(x) y_1'(x))/y_1(x) =  (-y_2''(x) - a_1(x) y_2'(x))/y_2(x)$ (note that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are never simultaneously $0$, as that would make the Wronskian $0$, so at least one of these will work at any point $x$).